# Substitute variable inside another variable in shell script without reassignment

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, variable-substitution

I am trying to substitute a variable inside another variable in shell script. but its showing as empty string. Below is the scenario.

1. Assigning "x" with string containing variable "abc"

```bsh
~$ x="new value is \${abc}"
~$ echo $x
new value is ${abc}
```

2. Below is content of script abc.sh, defining the value of abc->

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
abc="something='123:234'"
xyz=$@
echo $xyz
```

3. When executing command "sh abc.sh $x" getting below value.

actual -> new value is ${abc}

expected - > new value is something='123:234'

Please help solving above issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you insert the value `new value is ${abc}`, the `${abc}` part is just a string of characters.  This string is not reevaluated for expansions when you do `xyz=$@`.

To expand `${abc}` in the string, do the following in the script:

```
abc="something='123:234'"

eval "xyz=\"$1\""

printf '%s\n' "$xyz"
```

The `eval` takes a piece of shell code.  The given code does `xyz="$1"`, but with `$1` replaced by the command line argument (the string `new value is ${abc}`).  This statement is then reevaluated by the shell, assigning the correct string to the variable.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Kusalananda. Is there any other way where I dont need to edit the script and with some changes in variable "x" itself, results can be achieved.

Comment: @RDP No, there is not.